# Convert timezone offset "+00:00" to minutes

Tags: javascript, momentjs, timezone-offset

I have a function that returns `timezone offset` strings (like "+03:00")
And I want to convert this string to minutes offset("+03:00" should turn to 180) using moment.js or built-in plain javascript options

How can I do that?

Comment: Multiply hours by 60.

Comment: How can I parse it to get hours? Not with split (My boss won't accept it)

Comment: @NadavShabtai Why shouldn't split be used?

Comment: Because my boss wants to use official moment.js or javascript Date functions

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
moment().utcOffset("+03:00").utcOffset() // returns 180
moment().utcOffset("-09:00").utcOffset() // returns -540
```

Comment: you can accept your own answer so it's not open anymore

Answer (score 5):

Using vanilla JS you get the minutes using the below and it will honour positive and negative offsets.

```js
let offset = '-03:30';

let [h, m] = offset.split(':');

let hours = Number.parseInt(h);
let minutes = Number.parseInt(m);

let totalMinutes = hours * 60 + (hours < 0 ? (-minutes) : minutes);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just get the offset hour and then multiply it by 60 like below:

```js
function parseOffset(offset){
   var minutesOffset = (parseInt(offset[1] + offset[2]) * 60)

   console.log(parseInt(offset[0] + minutesOffset.toString()))
}
  
parseOffset("+03:00");
parseOffset("-02:00");
```

The above returns negative offset too.

The only way to get minutes from the date object in plain javascript is by using

`.getTimezoneOffset()` - but that doesn't seem to be the case based on your question.

There is no other way that I'm aware of to parse "+03:00" to minutes.

Comment: Can I export the hours using moment.js or Date?

Comment: Export hours? What do you mean by that? And why do you want to do that?

Comment: @NadavShabtai Sounds like this is a smaller part of something. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I just want to get the timezone offset represented by minutes without the split function (my boss won't accept this way)

Comment: @Adriani6  `minutesOffset` does not consider the minute part of the string and hence 
 `var minutesOffset = (parseInt(offset[1] + offset[2]) * 60) + parseInt(offset[4] + offset[5])`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [Parse Offset](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/zone-object/parse/) method of [momentjs timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/).

**Usage:**

```
var zone = moment.tz.zone('America/New_York');
zone.parse(Date.UTC(2012, 2, 19, 8, 30)); // 240
```